# Specific Time interval by user

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

While using a `start_time` and `end_time` in an HTML file for django application. I have used the time tag as follows:

```
<div>Start Time <input type="time" min="" max="" id="" name="start_time"></div>

<div>End Time <input type="time" min="" max="" id="" name="end_time"></div>
```

**But the constraint here is** - the user will give the timings varying from `5:00 AM to 4:59 AM`.

So, can anyone suggest what values should we need to have as min and max for `start_time` and `end_time` in the tags. Any other workaround is also welcomed.

Comment: How could your start time be after your end time O.o ?

Comment: @RashadKokash the time 4:59 AM is for the next day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem you are likely to run into when you set constraints manually.

Consider using a Bootstrap Time Picker, this way the constraints will be taken care of.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="md-form md-outline input-with-post-icon timepicker" darktheme="true">
      <input type="text" id="dark-version-example" class="form-control" placeholder="Select time">
      <label for="dark-version-example">Dark version, 24 hours</label>
      <i class="fas fa-envelope  input-prefix"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the example from [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/time-picker/)

If you wanted to define a shop that was open from 8:30 AM to 8:30 PM with a 30 minute for example, it would look as follows:

```
$('.event_date').datetimepicker({
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
      [moment().hour(0).minutes(0), moment().hour(8).minutes(30)],
      [moment().hour(20).minutes(30), moment().hour(24).minutes(0)]
   ]
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand the solution you've given above. I am using the Django framework and in which javascript might not run. So, something relevant to HTML or backend validation is what we can implement. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time). It should help you to set the intervals. For time values constraint, it would be good to have the end time unset imo, e.g. `5:00 AM to <Any_time>`. If <Any_time> is greater than start time then it will be the next day and less would mean it would be on the same day.